# Italic ampersand displayed weirdly?

Tags: characters, ampersand

I want an italic ampersand, yet it looks weird to me:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \textit{\&}
\end{document}
```

I just want an ampersand in italics, yet it should still look like an ampersand.

Comment: `\textit{\&}` is italic ampersand. Maybe you wish a slanted version: `\textsl{\&}`

Comment: The image you posted is fully recognizable as an ampersand to me. Yes, it's a different style, but that's no different from, e.g., the different styles of the lowercase "a": in most Romans it has an extra line at the top compared to the typical italic version "" that usually does not. This was a deliberate choice by the font designer. There are some fonts where the italic ampersand is much closer in style, e.g. `fouriernc` or `libertinus` or `stix2` if it really bothers you and you're able to switch.

Comment: @Sigur oh sorry I just noticed your comment. I can delete if you want a green tick:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, no problem. I like your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show is quite a common form of ampersand in italic fonts. In many ways it is *more* readable (as an e-t ligature) than the & form.  It can be viewed like `g` and *`g`* where the italic is a different shape, not simply slanted.

In the computer modern fonts you are using, there is a slanted & available via `\textsl`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
   \&  \textit{\&} \textsl{\&}
\end{document}
```